# How to perform a looping check on date/time mysql field for time values NOT equal to "00:00"?

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have a mysql table called "dobs" with a field called "dob" that is a date/time field.  So examples in that field could be:

- 2010-09-24 01:01:00
- 2008-09-24 00:00:00  (this means no time was entered, only a date.  I don't allow midnight to avoid confusion. If user tried to enter midnight, it would put "00:01:00" there)

I need to loop through all the fields and check to see if any of the TIME portions of that field is anything other than "00:00:00".

If just one of them has something other than "00:00:00" then I want the loop to stop because I now know what I need to know.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$sql = "SELECT dob FROM dobs";
        $getdobs= mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
        if (!$getdobs) {
        die("Database query failed: " . mysqli_error($connection));
        } else {
           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($getdobs)) {
            if (date("H:i", strtotime($row['dob'])!=="00:00") {
                //stop loop and set $times=yes
                $times="yes";
                break;  
            } else {
                //keep looping to look at next one
                $times="no";
            }
           }
}
```

Now I can check $times for either yes or no to do further things I need to do.  This code above works, I just worry that it's not the most efficient way to go about it. Two questions:

1. Did I "stop" the loop properly with "break"?
2. Is there a clearly more efficient way to perform this type of check?

Comment: you can do this in just hte query, no php needed

Comment: `SELECT dob FROM dobs WHERE  TIME(dob) !='00:00:00'`

Comment: Interesting.  I imagine doing it in the query will be faster?  I'll test it. Probably very fast either way, but still imagine your way will be faster.  Thanks!

Comment: much faster on any large data set

Answer (score 1):

Your code is spot on. Break is the correct reserve word to stop a loop. If your going to continue loop when the if statement isn't satisfied you can remove the else statement because it is irrelevant unless it never finds a date that is not 00:00 from the last row. Hope that helps.